# resteasy jax-rs not hitting my JAXB adapter when returning a Map

Tags: java, json, jboss, jaxb, resteasy

I'm using a JAXB adapter... `JAXBDateAdapter` that formats my dates in a standard format for the JSON-consuming clients.  I have a class `User` that has a `createdOn` field and it's annotated with `XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JAXBDateAdapter.class)` When I return any User object from my resources, everything is fine. The adapter is hit and the dates are formatted. However, I have another call that returns a map of users

```
@GET
Map<String, List<User>> getUsers() {  return ... }
```

I get back my json as

```
{"users" : [{ user in here }, { user in here } ]}
```

In this case my adapter never gets hit and the date comes back in a different form. How can I make it so that this also hits my adapter to format the dates properly?

Comment: Have you solved that already?

Comment: I think I ended up tracing through it and found that it was a problem in the json provider. When I upgraded to jackson 2.x, I think I upgraded resteasy to the latest and used the jackson-2 provider and things were ok. It's been quite a while since I looked at it so I can't say for sure, but I remember this was a path I went through.

Comment: Does the XmlJavaTypeAdapter get applied when you upgraded?